# Create Two-Column Dataframe Using Column Names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple lists similar to those below.

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(4,5,6)
c = c(7,8,9)
```

I know I can create a 3x3 dataframe using `cbind.data.frame`. However, I would like to create a 2 column data frame, where rows 1-3 have `a` in column 1, rows 4-6 have `b`, etc. It would look like a data frame created manually from:

```
data.frame(c('a','a','a','b','b','b'), c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can create a `key/value` pair `list` elements and use `stack` to convert it to a 2 column dataset.  The `mget` gets the values of the character object names in a `list` with key as the object names.

```
stack(mget(c('a', 'b', 'c')))
#  values ind
#1      1   a
#2      2   a
#3      3   a
#4      4   b
#5      5   b
#6      6   b
#7      7   c
#8      8   c
#9      9   c
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create the 3x3 `data.frame` and `melt` it:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),b = c(4,5,6),c = c(7,8,9)))

#  variable value
#1        a     1
#2        a     2
#3        a     3
#4        b     4
#5        b     5
#6        b     6
#7        c     7
#8        c     8
#9        c     9
```